# How to calculate this Fourier inverse?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

$$
F(t) = (1-t^{2})^{3} \mathbf{1}_{\{|t|<1\}}(t)
$$
Then 
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int F(t) e^{-itx} dx = ?
$$

Thanks!

Comment: Just a typo in the integral could you change the $F(t)$ by $F(x)$ And to calculate the value you can expand and just use integration par part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood your notation correctly, in Mathematica I get
$$
f(x)=\frac{96}{x^7}\left((x^2-15)x \cos(x) + 3(5-2x^2)\sin(x) \right)
$$
you can change in bounds on the inverse transform to be between $-1$ and $1$, because of the limited domain.
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-1}^1 (1-t^2)^3 \exp(i t x)\;dt
$$
note that the constant of $2 \pi$ can vary on the definition used, and the inverse transform has the opposite sign in the exponential to the forward transform.